# How to bind the selected option from the drop down to a reactjs state property in functional component and show it to side of the dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am new to react js. I have written a code for selecting the option for the perticular question. I just want to display the selected option next to the drop down. But when I selected the option it is displaying the same value for all the questions. could anyone please help me in resolving this.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState("");

  const optionchanged = (e) => {
    setSelect(e.target.value);
  };

  const questions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      qst: "which country you are from",
      options: ["select", "USA", "UK", "Australia", "India"]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      qst: "What is your country code",
      options: ["select", "+1", "+44", "+61", "+91"]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ "text-align": "left" }}>
      {questions.map((quest) => (
        <div>
          {/* displaying the question */}
          <p>
            {" "}
            {quest.id}. {quest.qst}
          </p>
          {/* showing the options */}
          <select onChange={optionchanged}>
            {quest.options.map((option) => (
              <>
                <option> {option}</option>
              </>
            ))}
          </select>
          {/* selected option showing next to the dropdown */}
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span style={{ color: "blue" }}>{select} </span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}



here is the output I got , here the second question also giving the same option without selecting it.
 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFyu8.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need store the value related to every `select` separately, to achieve your goal, you can define different states, or you can store values in an object instead of string, like this:

```js
function App() {
  const [select, setSelect] = React.useState({});

  const optionchanged = (e, id) => {
    setSelect( select => ({ ...select, [id]: e.target.value })  );
  };

  const questions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      qst: "which country you are from",
      options: ["select", "USA", "UK", "Australia", "India"]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      qst: "What is your country code",
      options: ["select", "+1", "+44", "+61", "+91"]
    }
  ];
        
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ "text-align": "left" }}>
      {questions.map((quest) => (
        <div>
          {/* displaying the question */}
          <p>
            {" "}
            {quest.id}. {quest.qst}
          </p>
          {/* showing the options */}
          <select onChange={e => optionchanged(e, quest.id)}>
            {quest.options.map((option) => (
                <option> {option}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
          {/* selected option showing next to the dropdown */}
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span style={{ color: "blue" }}>{select[quest.id]} </span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different state variables for both fields. As of now both the field values are stored to the same state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).